# Is there a library like Rails for Lua?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lua

Is there a library like Rails for Lua?

Comment: Is really lua used for web development? I thought it excels in other environments, such as embedded high level language.

Comment: From what I understand, the actual Lua language is very minimalistic.  So I would think anything could be built on top of it, including a Rails-like framework.

Comment: Answers are outdated, take a look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings for up-to-date info.

Comment: Post that as an answer @develCuy and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 22):

Entirely like Rails, I'd say no. But take a look at the [Kepler Project](http://www.keplerproject.org/) and specially [Orbit](http://orbit.luaforge.net/), which is a MVC framework. I'm doing web stuff with it and it is really fun to work with. You don't have the scaffolding stuff you have in Rails, but besides that, it 
has an orm, a templating engine ([Cosmo](http://cosmo.luaforge.net)), so you can get going.

Answer (score 4):

[Tir](http://tir.mongrel2.org/) is a simple Lua + [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) web framework written by Zed Shaw.

Answer (score 2):

For building web applications in Lua (or MoonScript) `lapis` might be a fitting solution. It seems to be stable enough as known sites like http://itch.io
or http://luarocks.org are built with it.

http://leafo.net/lapis/

*Lapis includes URL routing, HTML Templating, CSRF Protection and Session support, PostgreSQL/MySQL backed models, schema generation and migrations in addition to a collection of useful functions needed when developing a website*.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing and here is a list that I found on [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=web&Search=Search).

Haven't tried any of them so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

By Rails, I am assuming that you are looking for a MVC web framework. Check out [Sailor](http://sailorproject.org/). It's an open source framework and you can follow it's development on [GitHub](https://github.com/sailorproject/sailor).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely check out **Lapis**. It's a very lightweight and fast framework for OpenResty. I've really been enjoying it and predict it will have a bright future!

http://leafo.net/lapis/

As you would expect with anything built to leverage OpenResty, it's benchmarks are insanely good: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r12&hw=peak&test=query

The author of Lapis also wrote a CoffeeScript-like language for Lua called MoonScript which is quite nice: http://moonscript.org/

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the actual question, check out the lua-users.org wiki [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings) for a list of web frameworks available. I have some experience with [Sailor](http://www.sailorproject.org) which seems like a good choice.